# Facebook send dialog: adding a linebreak in the description

Tags: facebook, url

This is an URL I have to send an invitation to an app of mine:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/send?app_id=MY_APP_ID&
name=hola&
link=http://www.aWebSite.com&
picture=http://www.aWebSite.com/im01068442.jpg&description=participar!&
redirect_uri=http://elsuperdt.com
```

I'm trying to have a linebreak included within the description, but I just haven't found a way to do so. How do I do it?

Comment: I don't understand why my question was downvoted.. does anybody know the answer?

Comment: Don't understand why it was downvoted either. I have the exact same problem, but unfortunatly have no solution.

Comment: Facebook explicitly states you should use App Requests for invitations to an app instead of the Send dialog.
 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/send/
 
"In general, applications on Facebook should use Requests when communicating in game status (its your turn), inviting people to use an application..."

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same issue and eventually gave up. Facebook seems to have gone to great lengths to avoid letting us have any linebreaks in the description.

The one thing you can do is add a &caption=first%20line which gets you one linebreak between the caption and the description. (There's a pretty short limit on how long the caption can be though - something like 80 characters.)

Update: this no longer works for `send` dialogs. It does still work for `feed` dialogs

Comment: i was starting to get worried with both downvotes believing my question was waaaaaay beyond dumbb... Thanks for the tip, i'll keep trying to find a more suitable workaround, if i can't, the bounty is yours! thanks again

Comment: Ok! Thats as close as we got.. thanks @Nathan, still trying to figure out why those downvotes when it turns out nobody knew! Thanks againn!

Comment: @Nathan Friedly how do I add a caption exactly?

Comment: Doh. It doesn't work for `send` dialogs any more. It does work for `feed` dialogs though. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

Try using `<center></center>` this will create a new line in Facebook dialog description.

Answer (score 1):

Try including `%0D%0A` in your description where you want the line break to be. This is the URL-encoded equivalent of a line break.

Comment: Just tried it... didn't work! Thanks though, more ideas are more than welcome!

Answer (score 1):

\n works in message but not in name parameter

Answer (score 0):

I tried `center></center>` and `%0D%0A`. Both worked... for a split second.  You could see the breaks upon page load, and then, like evil magic, facebook took it away and it was all scrunched up. Too bad. I'm trying to share a daily schedule, which would look much better with line breaks.

Answer (score -4):

You can use blanks that are not posted to facebook in the length of the feed so the line breaks.

Or you just style your post by adding ".........." in the end of each line. This way people would maybe be more attracted to your post as they are eyecatching.