# Add line-break to open graph meta tag

Tags: facebook-like, facebook-opengraph

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Facebook send dialog: adding a linebreak in the description](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7348980/facebook-send-dialog-adding-a-linebreak-in-the-description)

I created open graph meta tag for facebook, google+ buttons and it works well with a single line in description. But I tried to add a line break in between paragraph in description using `'\n'`, `'\n\r'`, `'<br>'`, `'<br \>'`, etc, none of them work.

Any solution or work-around? Thanks.

Comment: Until now, I'm still not able to find a solution to this issue, anyone ?